# Inner Join is giving error #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: sql, join

I have been trying to do a Inner Join in SQL. But an error is coming, e.g. #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias. I have tested the individual query and working well.
Can any body help in this issue?

Here is the statement:

```
SELECT OQT.Cuspoit_cuspoid, OQT.Cuspoit_partno, OQT.Cuspoit_qty, CQT.`Chalanit_qty ` 
FROM (
  SELECT Cuspoit.`Cuspoit_cuspoid` , Cuspoit.`Cuspoit_partno` , Cuspoit.`Cuspoit_qty` 
  FROM `Cuspoit` 
  WHERE Cuspoit.`Cuspoit_cuspoid` = 'CPO-1306023'
) AS OQT
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT CQT.`Chalanit_cuspoid` , CQT.Chalanit_partno, CQT.Chalanit_qty
  FROM (

    SELECT Chalanit_cuspoid, Chalanit_partno, SUM( `Chalanit_qty` ) AS Chalanit_qty
    FROM `Chalanits` 
    WHERE `Chalanit_cuspoid` = 'CPO-1306023'
    GROUP BY Chalanit_partno
  )
) AS CQT ON OQT.`Cuspoit_cuspoid` = CQT.`Chalanit_cuspoid `
```

Comment: Inside CQT you use another subselect.  That's the one that's missing the alias.

Comment: With indentation, it becomes clearer.  The innermost derived table has no alias, right before `AS CQT`, following `GROUP BY Chalanit_partno`

Answer (score 1):

The second subquery has a subquery with no alias.  Try someting like this:

```
SELECT OQT.Cuspoit_cuspoid, OQT.Cuspoit_partno, OQT.Cuspoit_qty, CQT.`Chalanit_qty ` 
FROM (
  SELECT Cuspoit.`Cuspoit_cuspoid` , Cuspoit.`Cuspoit_partno` , Cuspoit.`Cuspoit_qty` 
  FROM `Cuspoit` 
  WHERE Cuspoit.`Cuspoit_cuspoid` = 'CPO-1306023'
) AS OQT
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT CQT.`Chalanit_cuspoid` , CQT.Chalanit_partno, CQT.Chalanit_qty
  FROM (

    SELECT Chalanit_cuspoid, Chalanit_partno, SUM( `Chalanit_qty` ) AS Chalanit_qty
    FROM `Chalanits` 
    WHERE `Chalanit_cuspoid` = 'CPO-1306023'
    GROUP BY Chalanit_partno
  ) cqt  --< THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS
) AS CQT ON OQT.`Cuspoit_cuspoid` = CQT.`Chalanit_cuspoid `
```